# ¿Cómo se puede iniciar el reproductor de audio por defecto en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

¿Cómo se puede abrir el reproductor de Audio que este asociado como defecto en Android? sin especificar fuente de sonido, es decir abrir solamente.

Comment: @Mariano cuando una pregunta es muy concreta, poner código es irrelevante, otra cosa seria que devolviese un error

Comment: entiendo tu punto y sé que no siempre es necesario. No estoy hablando necesariamente de poner código, pero creo que la pregunta se podría beneficiar de un poco de contexto. Por ejemplo, ¿qué se encuentra en una búsqueda online y por qué no te serviría? O qué método está relacionado y por qué no aplica. Sé que sos el usuario que más preguntas ha hecho en SOes y que estos temas los tenés claros, pero era una forma de recomendar ampliar una pregunta con la idea de aportar la mayor calidad posible entre todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto deberia abrir el reproductor pero no reproducir nada

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=15){        
    Intent intent=Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
    Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//Min SDK 15
    startActivity(intent);
}else{
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");//Min SDK 8
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Como lo haria si quiero psaarle un archivo de video?

Answer (score 0):

El intent que abrirá el reproductor de música es ACTION_VIEW

```
public void playMedia(Uri file) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(file);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Recuerda poner el intent filter entre la actividad, en el manifest

```
<activity ...>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:type="audio/*" />
    <data android:type="application/ogg" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```